# How do I get the particular value from same multiple div class name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="hMZdhd">Additional access
  <div class="OcFGjf">
  <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your approximate age</div>                         
  <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your language preferences</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hMZdhd">March 20, 12:06 PM</div>
```

I want to access the one value of div class "hMZdhd", but my javascript code returns all the values of class with name "hMZdhd".

Here's My sample javascript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd")[0].innerHTML
```

***Output Should be:*** March 20, 12:06 PM

Any Help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: you need to use innertext not innerhtml. see my answer below.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I always need the last div and index is not fixed

Comment: In, `document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd")[0].innerHTML`, Replace `0` with `document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd").length - 1`. This will always return the last element.

Comment: Is this always the last ?

Comment: @TakitIsy yes always last, but index is not fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you want to display is at the last index (`.length - 1`) of the array returned by your class selection,

`[0]` returns the first element matching the class `hMZdhd` (i.e. `<div class="hMZdhd">Additional access[…]</div>`).

```js
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd");
console.log(elms[elms.length - 1].innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="hMZdhd">Additional access
  <div class="OcFGjf">
    <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your approximate age</div>                         
    <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your language preferences</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hMZdhd">March 20, 12:06 PM</div>
```

You can try `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd"))` to display the full array returned by `getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd")` in this kind of situation. It's often helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need the content of last `div` with that class you can calculate the index of last `div` item and get the content like:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd");
var val = element[element.length-1].innerHTML;
console.log(val);
```

```html
<div class="hMZdhd">Additional access
  <div class="OcFGjf">
  <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your approximate age</div>                         
  <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your language preferences</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hMZdhd">March 20, 12:06 PM</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **innerText** instead of **innerHTML** on **last index**.

Your code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd")[0].innerHTML
```

Code you want:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd");
var outputYouWant = items[items.length-1].innerText;
```

EDIT: Code edited to get last item. BTW innerText is the truest answer for the asked output, not innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("hMZdhd")[0];
div.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div class="hMZdhd">Additional access
  <div class="OcFGjf">
  <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your approximate age</div>                         
  <div role="listitem" class="wnt0Xd">View your language preferences</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hMZdhd">March 20, 12:06 PM</div>
```

Comment: Output Should be: March 20, 12:06 PM

Comment: Please review it now.

Comment: hiding the first appearance?? why??

Comment: I had done this because the expected outcome is `March 20, 12:06 PM` which is the innerHTML of the last div.

Comment: Who said anything about changing the view for user?